# Роутинг в Angularjs

Tags: route, javascript, html5, angularjs, маршрутизация

Добрый день.

Перечитал вроде немало по роутингу в Angularjs, но не могу реализовать задуманное.

Есть такие url:

```
-Mysite.com/Students                 //либо Mysite.com/#/Students,не используя
-Mysite.com/StudentInfo/333          //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
-Mysite.com/Disciplini
```

На странице несколько вкладок: "Студенты", "Дисциплины" и др. Вкладка "Студенты" содержит слева список студентов, справа - информацию по выбранному студенту.

Хочу сделать следующее: чтобы страница `Mysite.com/#/Students` отображала открытую вкладку "Студенты" и подгрузила список студентов в левую часть сайта. Правая часть на данном этапе пустая. Потом пользователь выбирает конкретного студента, и в правую часть подгружается инфо о студенте.

Как это реализовать, чтобы по переходу по ссылке `Mysite.com/StudentInfo/333` открылась вкладка со списком студентов слева и информацией о студенте 333?

Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

Подобное приходилось реализовывать с помощью ui-router, 
Там возможно использовать более гибкую настройку связанных вью. Стоит почитать https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?